# Why my screen saver on android TV pauses the live stream?

Tags: android, android-studio, video-streaming, live

I am very new to this , just used the TV app building inside android studio and added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

inside the Androidmanifest.xml .
When I made an APK file to test it on my TV, as soon as the screen saver kicks in, it pauses the live stream and goes to screen saver.

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

The current best practice, or Android recommended way to keep he screen on for movies etc is:

```js
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    }
}
```

More info including the example above in Java and Kotlin here:https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Note that your manifest extract above is telling the system that this app needs wake lock permission, rather than actually setting it, in case that was the cause of the confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much Mick for your advice, and also clearing that WAKE LOCK , I will try that tonight and post the results.

Comment: @Mick- I added the line suggested to the Kotlin Main Activity but it still didn't stop the screen saver to get activated. here is the code ,I wish there was a way to send you the whole package somehow. (code is in the next comment)

Comment: 'package com.example.mytv

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

/** Loads [PlaybackVideoFragment]. */
class PlaybackActivity : FragmentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.content, PlaybackVideoFragment())
                    .commit()
        }
    }
}'

Comment: @Alex - its worth reading through the l inked documentation in detail as its should help explain the background. One quick note - you need to add the flag to the activity you actually want to keep the screen on in, which may not be (likely is not) your main activity.

Comment: Thank you Mick, I will try your suggestion and post the results. I have been reading for days but I will read more.